# jQuery each() behavior if changing DOM within loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, each

What is the behavior of jquery when using each() loop? Is it:

1. look for the first object, execute function, look for the next object...
2. gather all objects in a container, then execute the function on each of them
3. other (what exactly?)

An example, where it is relevant:

```
<div id="a">
   A
   <div id="b">
      B
   </div>
</div>
<div id="c">
    C
</div>
```

If I execute this javascript:

```
$('div').each(function(index){
   alert($(this).html());
   $(this).remove();
}
```

Will I see three alerts or only two?

Comment: I already fixed the formatting - you have special button to format code it looks like `{ }` in the editor.

Comment: Regarding the last question, you'll see three alerts, see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/5fdU5/

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - when I used the {} button and inside html tags, they were not escaped and I only saw A B C, not the divs in my example. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: you should mark the whole block of code with the mouse and only then click the code icon `{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of what action you will perform on a selection, **jQuery will make that selection before applying that action**. By which I mean `$('div')` is a selector, the selection process happens before and regardless of the other chained methods (such as `each()`). This is a product of the language, since `$()` must be evaluated before a method can be called upon it.

If that selection grabbed three divs from your page, then there are now 3 jQuery objects in a list ready to be iterated over. **You can prove this by doing**:

```
$('div').length
```

Thus you are iterating over an array with three indexes (0, 1, 2), if you remove the div from the DOM for index 1, the next iteration of the `each()` callback will still be for the object at index 2. Checkout this live demo for proof:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/HYJa4/

Comment: that's a little misleading, it's really javascript that performs the `$('div')` first and then the `each()`, not jQuery

Comment: @davin jQuery is Javascript :). Nevertheless your point stands if you are saying that it is a product of the languages evaluation process.

Comment: that's precisely what i was referring to

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will behave as you've described in #2. You'll see three alerts:

1. "A <div> B </div>"
2. "B"
3. "C"

However, since div B is inside div A, it will be removed with div A. jQuery still knows about it, and will alert its contents, but it will have already been removed by that time. So, although you get three alerts, you only have two removes (since it removes child elements).

Answer (score 0):

2 is the answer.

jQuery gathers a list of matching elements, then loops over the list.

One important think though, do not remove any element that can be mached that has not already been processed or you will risk getting a reference not found error.

Comment: Is it really the case (risking getting the error)? It seems that the examples above show that there is no error even while removing elements further in the loop (because they are still kept inside the jQuery object) - am I wrong?

Comment: If you remove the DOM element jQuery points to yes, espesially if you try to access siblings to the element. If you removed it it is no onger part of the DOM and any methods that return information relating the elements position in the DOM should fail.